# Puppeteer "Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null"

Tags: javascript, testing, puppeteer

I'm getting the error from the title for this function:

```
  it('should change comment status to SOLVED',
    async function() {
      await page.click("#view_replies3");
      await change_comment_status(page, 5, 'SOLVED');
  }).timeout(0);
```

After debugging I have figured out that the problem is in the function "change_comment_status()":

```
async function change_comment_status(page, comment_id, status) {
  const selector = "input.custom-control-input[name='" +
    comment_id.toString() + "']";
  page.waitForSelector(selector);

  await page.evaluate(selector => {
    let element = document.querySelector(selector);
    element.click();
  }, selector);
}
```

the variable 'element' is null after the call

- https://pastebin.com/UajS29ps
- all the elements appear correctly in the page and the page looks like is fully loaded during the test running

Thanks, guys!